# My PHP-based interactive voting system isn't working

Tags: php

I am still new to PHP and trying to create an interactive voting system. I used 2 arrays that hold names in a string. I used

```
<?php
$array(...,...);
$array2(...,...);
$random = $array; 
$random2 = $array2; 
shuffle($random); 
shuffle($random2);
?>
```

to output name randomly.

I then created a form with

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()" value="<?php echo array_pop($random);?>" name="name" />
</form>

<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()" value="<?php echo array_pop($random2);?>" name="haventseen" />
</form>
```

At this point all the names show up randomly in a button to click, and when clicked, 2 new ones show up. The problem I am having is storing the information in the database. Since it is a voting system, I'd like to store them in DB and each time a user clicks on the button +1 is added to that particular name. And when the "haventseen" button is clicked +1 to that name in the button above in the haventseen row. This is how my table is set up:

It is a MySQL 5.0 database.

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY (id)
name VARCHAR(80)
vote INT(11)
haventseen INT(11)
```

Here is my code so far.

```
<?php
 $dbname = "db_name";

    $con=mysql_connect
("local","root","pass");
    if(!$con)
    {
    die ('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());  
    }
    echo ('Connected');

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO `table_name` (`name`)  VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}')";
$sql="INSERT INTO `table_name` (`name`)  VALUES ('{$_POST['haventseen']}')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. But this setup isn't putting anything into the database (I changed some names for this post) even when all the names are correct. Some sample code would be really nice! But if its too much trouble please talk me through some steps I can take.

Comment: Dump any tutorials that use `mysql` as it's deprecated and insecure. You should use `mysqli` or better yet `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks ill start there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to SUBMIT the form to able to get the values with $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST.

The following part refreshes the page instead of submit the form. I believe that's the problem.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()" value="<?php echo array_pop($random);?>" name="name" />
</form>

<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()" value="<?php echo array_pop($random2);?>" name="haventseen" />
</form>
```

Try to use "submit" instead of "button".

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo array_pop($random);?>" name="name" />
</form>

<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo array_pop($random2);?>" name="haventseen" />
</form>
```

Also, you have to put them into the same form if you want to get them both at once. In this case, your approach should be;

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="/*SUBMIT THE FORM*/" value="<?php echo array_pop($random);?>" name="name" />
</form>

<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="/*SUBMIT THE FORM*/" value="<?php echo array_pop($random2);?>" name="haventseen" />
</form>
```

Comment: Everything works now except the names in the array don't save to the data base just numbers. Any thought on how i can fix this?